# Where are the eclipse-collections source jars?

Tags: eclipse-collections

I couldn't find these artifacts:

- eclipse-collections-api-7.1.0-sources.jar
- eclipse-collections-7.1.0-sources.jar

I ended up creating them myself, but that was a pain since the build is broken on OSX & Windows.

Comment: How ere you going about finding them?

Comment: @nitind I thought I had googled for "eclipse collections source jars". That same google search still does not provide a good link, except for this SO question, which is already #2 in the results. I had also followed the [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/) download link to [mvnrepository.com](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.collections/eclipse-collections-api/8.0.0), which has binaries only. Not knowing maven well, I thought I was looking at maven central and that the source artifacts were not there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to download the sources for Eclipse Collections 7.1.0 from Maven Central [here](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.eclipse.collections%22%20AND%20v%3A%227.1.0%22).